# How to test for mongoose model validation errors with Jest using async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

I'm trying to test a simple model validation using Jest.
The model is as follows:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')
const { isEmail, isAlphanumeric, isNumeric, isAlpha } = require('validator')


const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    validate(v) {
      return isEmail(v)
    }
  }
})

const User = model('User', userSchema)
```

Then, in my test file, I have the following setup:

```
const User = require("../models/user");

const invalidUser = {
  name: "David",
  email: "david@invalid"
};

const validUser = {
  name: "David",
  email: "david@example.com"
};
```

Now, when I try running a test using callbacks, I get the desired result (err is `null`):

```
test("Should not validate user without valid email", done => {
  const user = new User(invalidUser);
  user.validate(err => {
    expect(err).not.toBeNull();
    done();
  });
});
```

However, when I refactor that test to use async/await, it just passes every time, even if I change `invalidUser` to have a valid email (which should case the test to fail):

```
test("ASYNC Should not validate user without valid email", async () => {
  try {
    const user = new User(invalidUser);
    await user.validate();
  } catch (e) {
    expect(e).not.toBeNull();
  }
});
```

My guess is `e` is not correctly populating with the error from `validate()`, but why is that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your async version is not right, as it will always finish successfully. Take into account that:

- When you use an `invalidUser`, the `catch()` block will be called with your expected error, so you’ll check `not.toBeNull()` and everything will be ok.
- When you use a `validUser`, the `user.validate()` promise will be resolved without errors, so your `catch` block will not be executed and your test case will finish successfully, too.

So you need a different approach, to ensure your test is rejected when the `validate()` promise is resolved successfully:

```js
test("ASYNC Should not validate user without valid email", async () => {
  let error = null;

  try {
    const user = new User(invalidUser);
    await user.validate();
  } catch (e) {
    error = e;
  }

  expect(error).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A more correct approach would probably be to use jest's `.rejects` and `.toThrow()` like [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3601#issuecomment-434793734). In your case:

```
test("ASYNC Should not validate user without valid email", async () => {
    const user = new User(invalidUser);
    await expect(user.validate()).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

And if you want a specific error message you can test it by adding it as an argument like this: `.toThrow('error message goes here')`. More on this in [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects).